# How does print_list() Iterate though a Linked List in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

The code works and outputs 1,5, and 6.

After print_list(), prints the first value ( 1 ), how does temp = temp.next result in temp.value being 5 on the next pass.

I am missing something but I've been at this for days. I just don't understand how temp.next is pointing at 5 or the next node.

I also understand that temp, head, and tail are pointers. Please help, I am trying to learn what every line of code is doing.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:

    def __init__ (self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)
        self.head = new_node
        self.tail = new_node
        self.lenth = 1

    def print_list(self):
        temp = self.head 
        while temp is not None:
            print(temp.value)
            temp = temp.next

    def append(self, value):   
        new_node = Node(value)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        else: 
            self.tail.next = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        self.lenth =+ 1
        return True


my_linked_list = LinkedList(1)
my_linked_list.append(5)
my_linked_list.append(6)
my_linked_list.print_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

When thinking about a linked list data structure, you can conceptualize the structure as a list of boxes chained together, with the first box connected to the next, that one connected to the next, and so on, until you reach the last box and there's nothing it's chained to. Here's a rough visual demonstration:

`[5] -> [7] -> [9] -> [3] -> None`

This linking between boxes is denoted by having the first node of the linked list (a.k.a the *head*), have a reference to the next box in the list. In your code example this reference is stored in the `next` attribute. And this next node has a reference stored in *it*, which points to the next, next node. And this process continues on, creating the chain-like behavior I mentioned above.

What `print_list` is doing is starting at the head of the linked list, printing the head's data, and then using the reference the head has to the next box in the linked list to get that next box, print it's data, and then use this next boxes reference to get the next box in the list. This process continues on until the last box is reached, which has no further reference, so the code terminates (this is what the `while temp is not None:` condition checks for).

I commented each line below to connect what I said a bit more concretely to the actual code:

def print_list(self):
# Set temp to be equal to the first box in the list
temp = self.head

```
# temp will be set to none when we try to set it to be equal to 
# the next box the last box in the list is pointing to. So we
# know we've reached the end of the list when temp is none, 
# meaning we should break out of the loop and finish.
while temp is not None:
    # Print the data in the current box, starting with head...
    print(temp.value)
    # And then get the next box in the list so we can print it's data.
    temp = temp.next
```

Comment: Thanks, for taking the time to answer and breaking it down.

How is temp.next pointing to the Next box. What line of code changed it from None.

In my head ( I know it's wrong ) temp.next = None. 

Meaning from when the linkedList was initialized, when did head.next start pointing to the next node.

Comment: @Tychius Sure. the append method of the code you presented is responsible for adding a new box to the list, and the making sure what use to be the last box, now points to the inserted box, which is now the last box.

Comment: Hey, Last question. Do you know what line of code changes the first nodes ( 1 ) next attribute. to point to the next node. I am having alot of trouble understanding when did the first node start pointing to the next node. It has to be in the append method but what line ?